# Defending against stack overflow by user scripts

Tags: c++, security, scripting, stack-overflow

C++ has limited stack space but no way for functions to check whether there's enough space left for them to run. I don't know what to do about this when writing script bindings.

For example:

```
class Container : Widget {
  void addChild(WidgetPtr child) { ... }

  void draw(Canvas& canvas) {
    for (auto child : m_children) {
      child.draw();
    }
  }
};
```

A malicious script can do this to crash the program:

```
var a = new Container()
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  var b = new Container()
  a.addChild(b)
  a = b
}

a.draw() // 10000000 nested calls ---> stack overflow
```

There's also callback problem:

```
void doSomething(std::function<void()> callback) {
  callback();
}
```

If wrapped using something like this:

```
ScriptValue doSomething_Wrapper(ScriptArgs args) {
  doSomething([&]() { args[0].callAsFunction(); });
}
```

Crashed using:

```
function badCallback() { doSomething(badCallback) }
doSomething(badCallback)

...
doSomething_Wrapper
doSomething
ScriptValue::callAsFunction
...
doSomething_Wrapper
doSomething
ScriptValue::callAsFunction
...
BOOM!
```

What's the most idiomatic way to defend against this with least inconvenience?

What do browsers written in C++ (Firefox, Chrome) do?

What can I do not to introduce a vulnerability like this by accident?

Comment: One may of course count call stack depth manually, or traverse the data without recursion.

Comment: Your OS may allow to limit the resources a process or thread uses. E.g. `setrlimit(2)` in linux.

Comment: @chi And how does this prevent crashes if it overflows?

Comment: @deviantfan it does not prevent the process to crash, but it prevents it to allocate so much memory that might make _other_ processes to crash because they run out of memory. Moreover, crashes in c++ can also arise from memory mismanagement, e.g. null pointer dereferences, use-after-delete, etc.

Comment: @chi Didn´t think of that perspective ... in some cases surely useful

Comment: @deviantfan I've probably misread the question, then. Perhaps you don't want to defend the system by  malicious scripts. Rather, you want to defend the script from the resource limit: e.g. you want to do `if (still some space) { recurse(); } else { errorOut(); }` so that crashes are avoided in a safe way. That's interesting, but I don't have a real solution for that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a "malicious" script could cause a stack overflow, like you describe, it can´t harm the program more than causing crashes that way (at least on modern OS where the stack limit is actually checked and therefore it´s safe against overwrites of other important data).

If it´s critical that the program is running all the time, another process has to monitor it (and restart it if necessary. Not only because stack overflows, there are many more potential problems.).
Other than that, there isn´t much one can do if the OS stack is used. Dynamically allocating a large memory block for a single pointer in the stack and doing the whole memory management manually in this block is possible, but maybe impractical.

About eg. FIrefox: At least parts of the program are using an own memory management (but I´m not sure if it is relevant for plugins, scripts etc.). Additionally, there is a separate process `plugin-container.exe` (at least on Windows), and killing won´t kill Firefox (only the plugin part like Flash etc. won´t work anymore and the user gets a message about plugin crashing).